# Extn JS 4.2.0 Pagination for grid not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagination

Here is my app.js code

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*'
]);

var TOTAL = 94; //random

var fetchedData = function(){
    this.data = null;
    this.total = 0;
}




// code to create grid

Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('Person',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'fname', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lname', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'uid', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'isSup', type: 'boolean' },
            { name: 'upDate', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'upBy', type: 'string' }
        ]
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Person',
        pageSize : 2,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'supUserStore.json',
            reader: {type: 'json', root : 'data', totalProperty : 'total'}
        },
        sorters: [{
            property : 'Id',
            direction:'ASC'
        }],

    });
store.loadPage(1);
    // create the grid
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
              { header: 'First Name',dataIndex: 'fname' },
              { header: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'lname' },
              { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email'},
              { header: 'User ID', dataIndex: 'uid' },
              { header: 'Super Admin', dataIndex: 'isSup'},
              { header: 'Updated Date',dataIndex: 'upDate'},
              { header: 'Updated By',dataIndex: 'upBy'}
             ],
        // paging bar on the bottom
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
        }),
        renderTo:'grid-example',
        width: 350,
        height: 280,
    });

    // trigger the data store load
    store.loadPage(1);
});
```

And my json data is a json file:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 11,
    "data":  [
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com"}
            ] 
}
```

I'm able to load the grid with the data but I am unable to have pagination, all the records are loading in one single page. Please help me and advice me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working fine for me, I removed the top call to loadPage and also got rid of the fetchedData function as it wasn't being used.

I haven't changed anything else. Just wrapped the code in the launch function instead of in Ext.ready for the fiddle.

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j4f)

```
// data1.json
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 11,
    "data":  [
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jane","lname":"Smith","email": "j.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jsmith","isSup":false,"upDate":"11-19-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com" },
                { "fname": "Jim","lname":"Smith","email": "jm.smith@netapp.com", "uid": "jmsmith","isSup":true,"upDate":"11-23-2012","upBy":"aaron@netapp.com"}
            ] 
}

// app.js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.define('Person', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'fname',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'lname',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'email',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'uid',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'isSup',
                type: 'boolean'
            }, {
                name: 'upDate',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'upBy',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        // create the Data Store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Person',
            pageSize: 2,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'total'
                }
            },
            sorters: [{
                property: 'Id',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }],

        });

        // create the grid
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                header: 'First Name',
                dataIndex: 'fname'
            }, {
                header: 'Last Name',
                dataIndex: 'lname'
            }, {
                header: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email'
            }, {
                header: 'User ID',
                dataIndex: 'uid'
            }, {
                header: 'Super Admin',
                dataIndex: 'isSup'
            }, {
                header: 'Updated Date',
                dataIndex: 'upDate'
            }, {
                header: 'Updated By',
                dataIndex: 'upBy'
            }],
            // paging bar on the bottom
            bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
            }),
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 350,
            height: 280,
        });

        // trigger the data store load
        store.loadPage(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: its loading grid, but as you can see it shows 6 pages and shows same data in subsequent pages , please send me your data1.json file as well please, please look in to the issue .I appreciate you sir.

Comment: Thanks its working in fiddle but its not working in my local workspace , what could be the problem can some one please suggest .

Comment: I've added the data1.json file contents into the code above, you can see it in the fiddle too clicking the hamburger menu in the bottom left. Are you getting any errors in your browser console when running the code? The fiddle is using the exact code you provided above and also the same version so there shouldn't be any differences, can you create a fiddle out of the code you have?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to add data1.json to fiddle , please attach data1.json and give me the fiddle link.

Comment: same code is not working in my local workspace through browser where its working fine in fiddle ...

Comment: Please change the framework from 4.2 neptune to 5.1.0.107 neptune , all records are shown in same page ,pagination is not working as desired , I have replicated the issue

Comment: there are a few differences between the versions, for example, the `root` property on the proxy is called `rootProperty` in ExtJs 5

Comment: do u think what i am facing issue is becuse of version problems ,Thanks for the help..

Comment: what version are you using?